# How to Locate Autogenerate Id using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

1) I want to Locate Auto generated Id which is generated by JSF in java base application and that is different in all system.

2) What is the solution for locate that element using selenium webdriver?

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

You can locate any element using webdriver , in ur case you could xpath for locating and then use get attribute value to locate the auto generated ID.
Also u need to be more specific on your query , its always advisable to post html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modified or simple xpath with Different Functions.

1) contains()

```
//ul[contains(@id, 'Model')]
```

Where Model is constant part of your auto generated id.

2)  AND / OR

```
//*[contains(@id,'ABC') AND @class='xyz']
```

Replace And with OR for different condition

3) Sometime I have found ID is not contain any common text

```
//*[contains(@class,'qwe')]
```

### Now may be this will give you the list of elements

So you have two options

1. Use ele.get(0);
2. Use loop for all element and put condition for some element

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gwt-uid-41']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gwt-uid-31']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

// not sure if the above driver syntax is making SE WD wait

//the below have id's that are autogenerated/ want to know how to search the xpath of the element

// my script fails and says that the xpath not found because the id changes every time you login into the portal

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ext-gen153']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ext-gen163']")).click();
```